# Jest-Puppeteer test for a chrome extension - tests pass, but test suite fails due to the website needed

Tags: javascript, jestjs, window, puppeteer

I have a chrome extension I'm building for work to test an external website that I have no control over. The website has lots of internal errors that cause my test suite to fail, although the tests pass and the puppeteer workflow works. (I do feel sorry for actual users of that site). I have tried defining the missing references, but that just causes nothing to work. I have added various listeners to handle the website's errors, but no luck so far and while the test finishes it still fails the suite.

I will have to leave out any identifying information, but hopefully this will be a good place to start, and I will add as I can with requests.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: module is not defined


  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: getItemKeyValue is not defined

  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'template')


  ● Test suite failed to run

    ReferenceError: global is not defined

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       4 passed, 4 total
```

I've tried to ignore all the errors that are inherent in the website I have to test my extension on so that the test suite can pass. All that results from these is running the tests and passing them, and then failing the suite, or failing to run the website and therefor everything fails anyways because I define the missing variables..

```
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener('error', event => {
      console.warn('Error intercepted:', event.message);
      event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default handler
    });
  });

  //This error captures and gets past page errors, but doesn't work on the reference errors 
  page.on('pageerror', error => {
    if (error instanceof ReferenceError) {
      // Handle ReferenceError differently
      console.log('ref error', error)

    } else {
      // Handle or log other types of errors
      console.error('Page error:', error.message);
    }
  });

  // Stops all progress, but technically can run the suite :(
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.getItemKeyValue = window.getItemKeyValue || function () { }; // Stubbing the function
    window.global = window; // Defining 'global'
  });
```

Comment: How can the test suite fail, but the tests pass? This seems impossible. In any case, if the site has errors, it seems like you can either (a) ignore them if they're irrelevant to its operation or (b) ask whoever owns the site to fix them, since the tests _should fail_ if it's discovered legitimate problems in the site and it's actually broken. Test shouldn't be passing on a broken site--if they do, the suite is broken (giving false positives) in addition to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will need to set `exitOnPageError=false`.
Due to the default being `true` the test may pass but after that,
the page creates an error and the runner exits the test suit.

From docs https://github.com/argos-ci/jest-puppeteer?tab=readme-ov-file#configuring-jest-puppeteer :

```
  /**
   * Exit on page error.
   * @default true
   */
  exitOnPageError?: boolean;
```